# How can I enable KSM on CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

It's my first question here, and I'm just frustrated. I can't get to successfully enable KSM on my recently installed CentOS server.

The server is currently hosting a simple Java VM which allocates almost 1,2 GB of RAM, I want it to use less RAM, but KSM does not starts.

At every boot my system runs:

> echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run
>
> echo 500 > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_millisecs

```
full_scans 0
pages_shared 0
pages_sharing 0
pages_to_scan 50000000
pages_unshared 0
pages_volatile 0
run 1
sleep_millisecs 500
```

It seems like it's not properly setup in the kernel.

One way or another, running commands for testing its existence like "service ksm restart" or "service ksmd restart" outputs:

> ksm: unknown service

Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/chap-KSM.html)?  That's the first result I got searching for "centos ksm".

Comment: Yes @larsks , it's the reason about why I'm asking, when I try 'service ksm start':

ksm: unknown service

Comment: The documentation tells you what package includes the `ksm` service.  Have you installed it?  It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks @larks , I've tried to install the package, but it tells me that it wasn't found. I've just tried: 'yum groupinstall "Virtualisation Tools" "Virtualization Platform"' without luck. Should I reboot after installation?

Answer (score 1):

- KSM operates only on RAM areas that are marked by special API calls.
- KSM is typically used with KVM virtual machines.
- Usually JVM does not tell KSM to scan its RAM.
- Assuming KSM is enabled on the host, one of the following might help:

  - Put JVM inside KVM.
  - Use a hack called kvm_preload.